# very simple ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am fiddling with ajax, the following doesn't work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.post("\tests\test1.php", function(data) {
      alert(data)
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click</button>
```

with test1.php

```
<?php

echo "Yes";

?>
```

The url is with respect to htdocs, so correct. Please point out the error.

Comment: It's a typo: You use `/`, not ``\``, in URLs. `\t` in a JavaScript string is a tab.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an incorrect url:
never use `"\tests\test1.php"`

Instead 
**"/tests/test1.php"**
is the correct approach.

So your code becomes:

```
$.post( "/tests/test1.php", function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

I would also recommend you to use the full URL exaple:

http://example.com/tests/test1.php

instead of /tests/test1.php. (although not required but considered as a good approach.)